# Dynamically change the css with media

Tags: javascript, css

I have a span and a link that I need to change the height on based on the screen width and I am wondering how to do this?

I have this so it straight out sets the height and it looks the way I want if the screen is square but I don't know how to use a media to accommodate for both ways.

HTML:

```
<span id="procs" class="space" style="display:block;height:35px;"><li ><a id="mpc" style="height:35px" href="adminreports.jsp?p=procs">Manage Processing Centers</a></li></span>
```

CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1280px) {
  #procs a {
    height: 35px;
  }
  #mpc {
   height: 35px;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. 
Please provide any guidance or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to change your code to fire after the DOM has been laid out... that way you can get the dimensions of the viewport.

Comment: `I have a span and a link that I need to change the height on based on the screen width and I am wondering how to do this?` - as a side note - Have a look at media queries in CSS instead of using JavaScript code to apply styles. It also has the added benefit of keeping your functional logic separated from your display logic.

Comment: Use @media to determine screen size and set specialised CSS

Comment: where is your ternary operator? looks like you can do it without using the so-called ternary operator? and you just want to ask for how to do it  using the so-called ternary operator?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the media queries and this did the trick:

```
<style media="screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1280px)">
#procs li a {height:auto}
</style>
```

Thank you.